# A sequence with Supremeum at least 1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

> **Problem:** Let $a_1, a_2, \cdots$ be an infinite sequence of positive reals such that
> $$
> |a_i - a_j| > \frac{1}{i+j}, \quad \forall i \ne j.
> $$
> Show that $\sup_i a_i \ge 1$.

I am able to do this problem if the sequence is increasing...because then I get something like,

$$a_i > \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{5} + \cdots \frac{1}{2i-1}.$$

However, when the sequence might oscillate I don't know how to show that a subsequence goes close to something at least $1$.

Comment: $a_n = -n$ is a counterexample.

Comment: This is from the IMO 2002 shortlist, there are solutions available online.

Comment: I get the feeling this is $\sup_i |a_i| \geq 1$, or $|\sup_i a_i| \geq 1$. Kindly correct the question.

Comment: I am sorry... I forgot to mention that $a_i > 0$

Comment: @MartinR Thanks!

Comment: Hello. I think you can rearrange the sequence, and by using the assumption given, you can find a lower bound for $c$ with some technique. I can write an answer if you want.

Comment: Take the first $M$ terms.  Rearrange to an ascending sequence, and follow what you've already done.  Consider what happens when $M \to \infty$.